# How can I validate an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is my first time building a custom validation , since trying to the regular ORM validations did not work. I have a model called AdGroup which belongs to another model called Car. I want to send prevent that a user creates a new Ad Group if they have not selected a car. Also the Car is a file.

```
class AdGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  validate :validate_car_id

  def validate_car_id
    car = Car.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if car.nil?
      errors.add(:car, "Select a car image")
    end
  end
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :make, :model, :year, presence: true                  
  validates :file, presence: true
  belongs_to :make
  has_many :ad_groups

  ...
end
```

Is an image that I am trying to select .

Comment: You should add your models definition to the question.

Comment: Is this the complete definition? You should add both `AdGroup` and `Car` models here, including the lines defining their association to each other (such as `has_many` or `belongs_to`).

Comment: If an answer was useful to you you should accept it or vote for it.

Answer (score 5):

Your Ad Group model needs to be associated with the Car model. AdGroup models should have `belongs_to :car` line and the Car model needs `has_many :ad_groups`.

To validate associated models you could use ActiveRecord's [`validates_associated`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated). Be sure to read the docs by the link for gotchas.

```
class AdGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car

  validates :car, presence: true
  validates_associated :car
end
```

When using `validates_associated` you don't have to do custom validation.

Comment: with validates_associated you don't need a custom validation anymore?

Comment: Under [certain conditions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#module-ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation-label-One-to-many+Example) `activerecord` autosaves its children when you don't specify `autosave: true`. Which adds an [`:invalid` error](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L365) to the parent model. `validates_associated` also adds an `:invalid` error. As a result you get the error twice...

Comment: ...You can specify `autosave: true` and not use `validates_associated`, then you supposedly get all the [children's errors](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L355-L362) (in place of one), but... is it usable? Does it work well?